# Generic function delegate for all enum values?

Tags: vb.net, enums

Consider the following code (console app, reduced test case):

```
Option Strict On

Module Module1

  Enum Enum1
    vDefaultEnum1
  End Enum

  Enum Enum2
    vDefaultEnum2
  End Enum

  Delegate Sub FunctionX(eValue As [Enum])

  Sub Function1(eValue As Enum1)
  End Sub

  Sub Function2(eValue As Enum2)
  End Sub

  Sub Main()
    Dim version As String = "1"
    Dim d As FunctionX
    Select Case version
      Case "1" : d = AddressOf Function1
      Case "2" : d = AddressOf Function2
      Case Else : Throw New NotImplementedException
    End Select
    d.Invoke(Enum1.vDefaultEnum1)
  End Sub

End Module
```

I am getting this error:

> Option Strict On does not allow narrowing in implicit type conversions between method 'Public Sub Function1(eValue As Enum1)' and delegate 'Delegate Sub FunctionX(eValue As System.Enum)'.

I understand this is because `Enum` [is a supertype](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for `Enum1` and `Enum2`, and the conversion would work fine the other way around. I am trying to avoid creating a new delegate for every `Enum` type (there will be ~50 of them per project).

Is there a way to implement this idea in the above example?

For this example, please assume that `Function1` and `Function2` are part of another assembly, to which I don't have access. They only differ by enum type parameter (different enums are used).

**Note:** The above is a reduced test case. In real life scenario, function signature are much bigger, with objects buried deep inside 10 levels of namespaces, so it looks ugly indeed to declare ~50 delegates like that in every project.

Comment: Doesn't `Delegate Sub FunctionX(Of T)(eValue As T)` help you in any way?

Comment: @dotNET: Actually it does. I did not realize I can use generics in a non-generic class without creating a separate class for it. A bit more code than I'd like, but definitely an improvement over the current approach. Please post as an answer, to be accepted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps generic delegates provide you a smarter option:

```
Delegate Sub FunctionX(Of T)(eValue As T)
```